# Karma PhamtonJS TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'React.renderComponent

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, phantomjs, karma-runner, webpack

I'm trying to set up React component testing using Webpack, Karma and PhantomJS.

I cannot seem to find why I get the following error when I run npm test:

PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8 0.0.0) Module Header should display text FAILED
        TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'React.renderComponent(instance, div)')

I have the following test file

```
'use strict';




describe('Module', function(){

  var component;

  beforeEach( function(){
    var React = require('react-addons');
    var TestUtils = React.TestUtils;
    var Header = require('../Header');
    var component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Header title="Test Title" />);
  });


  it('Header should display text', function(){

    expect(component.getDOMNode().textContent).toMatch(/Test Title/);
  });


});
```

It seems that TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(); is the problem , does anyone know how I can fix this ?

Thanks for your time.

I added the correct implementation here:  Thanks to Micheal for his help

```
var React = require('react/addons');
var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils; 
var Header = require('../Header'); 

describe('Module', function(){ var html; 
beforeEach( function(){ 
var componentInstance = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Header title="Test Title" />); 
html = componentInstance.getDOMNode().textContent; }); 

it('Header should display text', function(){ 
expect(html).toMatch(/Test Title/); 
}); 
});
```

....where the component just displays `<h1>{this.props.title}</h1>`

Comment: This is just a guess but can you try `var React = require('react/addons');` and `var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;`?

Comment: Yes solved the problem. Thanks Michael !

Comment: By the way my code is not correct  . For anyone following this see below:
var React = require('react/addons');
var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
var Header = require('../Header');


describe('Module', function(){

  var html;

  beforeEach( function(){

    var componentInstance = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Header title="Test Title" />);
   html = componentInstance.getDOMNode().textContent;
  });


  it('Header should display text', function(){

    expect(html).toMatch(/Test Title/);
  });
});    ....where the component just displays <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>

Comment: You should add that as an answer to your question instead of a comment.  I'm glad I could help :)